# DevExpress vs Aspose.pdf

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport, aspose.pdf

I need to choose a tool for an upcoming project in dotnet.
My requirement is to generate, sign, edit pdf reports.
The report will contain sections, subsections, tables, nested tables, images, header, footer, table of content etc.

I would like to know which tool is better in which aspect.

Answer (score 2):

The Aspose.pdf api is a powerful tool, but it is just API.
DevExpress XtraReports tool has a visual designer for report layout so you can "draw" your own complex layouts, embed the report designer into your application (or website) and export resulting document into the [pdf file](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/2574/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/store-and-distribute-reports/export-reports/export-to-pdf) with two lines of code:

```
var report = new MyReport();
report.ExportToPdf(stream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aspose.PDF for .NET API can be used to achieve all of your mentioned requirements. All product features are well documented and API references are available as well. Free support and Paid Support is also available for the API. You may request for a free, 30 day temporary license to test if this product satisfies your requirements. This is some brief information about the API and you may decide which option suits you well after testing and comparing both of these. You may visit respective website for further information.

**PS**: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks for input. I found a limitation in DevExpress around signing the PDF file multiple times. I would like to know some main features that are only possible in Aspose.PDF.

Comment: Please note that Aspose.PDF API mimics the behavior of Adobe Acrobat and almost all features which are available in Adobe Acrobat, are supported in Aspose.PDF API as well. You may explore respective documentation articles and API references for your kind reference.

Comment: @Rockr, tell me more about the DX-limitations. to broaden my horizons.

Comment: @k0st1x, since i don't have any working experience in either of the tools yet. I don't have any as of now. One thing i like in DevExpress is visually aligning the report layout and previewing instantly without running, which i guess is not possible in Aspose.PDF